# caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully

Tags: apache, centos, sentora

I'm a total newbie to this and I have already managed to mess my server (tried installing APC for PHP when this happened... Here is the log. Any ideas how to restore my server functions? :(

```
[Sun Jul 16 03:31:02.006590 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 23258] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jul 16 03:31:02.007261 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 23258] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 16 03:31:02.027374 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23258] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 16 03:31:02.027395 2017] [core:notice] [pid 23258] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jul 16 03:31:02.058755 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23258] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sun Jul 16 03:31:02.100133 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 23258] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jul 16 03:31:02.100780 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 23258] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 16 03:31:02.121136 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23258] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 16 03:31:02.121158 2017] [core:notice] [pid 23258] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jul 16 13:12:50.236464 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23258] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun Jul 16 13:14:51.100292 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 590] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Jul 16 13:14:51.155867 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 590] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jul 16 13:14:51.156790 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 590] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 16 13:14:51.369027 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 590] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 16 13:14:51.369071 2017] [core:notice] [pid 590] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jul 16 13:20:01.607625 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 590] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sun Jul 16 13:20:01.665046 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 590] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jul 16 13:20:01.665703 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 590] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 16 13:20:01.688267 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 590] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 16 13:20:01.688297 2017] [core:notice] [pid 590] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jul 16 13:30:02.019149 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 590] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sun Jul 16 13:30:02.082624 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 590] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jul 16 13:30:02.083308 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 590] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 16 13:30:02.104286 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 590] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 16 13:30:02.104312 2017] [core:notice] [pid 590] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jul 16 14:10:01.665938 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 590] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sun Jul 16 14:10:01.753728 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 590] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jul 16 14:10:01.754391 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 590] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 16 14:10:01.775101 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 590] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 16 14:10:01.775121 2017] [core:notice] [pid 590] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jul 16 19:56:39.477667 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 590] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun Jul 16 19:56:40.550616 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 18301] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Jul 16 19:56:40.574146 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 18301] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jul 16 19:56:40.574850 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 18301] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 16 19:56:40.602247 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18301] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 16 19:56:40.602280 2017] [core:notice] [pid 18301] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Jul 17 03:07:01.379026 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18301] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Mon Jul 17 03:07:01.443341 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 18301] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Jul 17 03:07:01.444065 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 18301] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Jul 17 03:07:01.465989 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18301] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 17 03:07:01.466011 2017] [core:notice] [pid 18301] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Jul 17 22:40:16.353423 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18301] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Mon Jul 17 22:41:47.131564 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 566] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Jul 17 22:41:47.180607 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 566] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Jul 17 22:41:47.182357 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 566] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Jul 17 22:41:47.439980 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 566] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 17 22:41:47.440032 2017] [core:notice] [pid 566] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Tue Jul 18 03:34:01.232302 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 566] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Tue Jul 18 03:34:01.308323 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 566] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Jul 18 03:34:01.309293 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 566] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Jul 18 03:34:01.332770 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 566] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 18 03:34:01.332791 2017] [core:notice] [pid 566] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Jul 19 00:23:21.218800 2017] [core:notice] [pid 566] AH00052: child pid 23334 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Jul 19 00:24:26.305481 2017] [core:notice] [pid 566] AH00052: child pid 17928 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Jul 19 00:33:21.458126 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 566] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Jul 19 00:34:55.085223 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 575] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Jul 19 00:34:55.123665 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 575] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 19 00:34:55.124399 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 575] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Jul 19 00:34:55.373515 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 575] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 19 00:34:55.373544 2017] [core:notice] [pid 575] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Jul 19 02:10:09.173702 2017] [core:notice] [pid 575] AH00052: child pid 11449 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Jul 19 02:13:17.444142 2017] [core:notice] [pid 575] AH00052: child pid 2643 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Jul 19 02:14:19.603707 2017] [core:notice] [pid 575] AH00052: child pid 12390 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Jul 19 02:22:53.412575 2017] [core:notice] [pid 575] AH00052: child pid 12273 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Jul 19 02:24:52.665096 2017] [core:notice] [pid 575] AH00052: child pid 12988 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Jul 19 02:29:16.976828 2017] [core:notice] [pid 575] AH00052: child pid 12429 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Jul 19 03:24:10.692202 2017] [core:notice] [pid 575] AH00052: child pid 14983 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Jul 19 03:31:01.588089 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 575] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Wed Jul 19 03:31:01.682642 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 575] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 19 03:31:01.685765 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 575] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Jul 19 03:31:01.707253 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 575] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 19 03:31:01.707280 2017] [core:notice] [pid 575] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Jul 19 14:27:54.516364 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 575] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Jul 19 14:29:26.805786 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 587] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Jul 19 14:29:26.860112 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 587] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 19 14:29:26.860800 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 587] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Jul 19 14:29:27.133553 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 587] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 19 14:29:27.133603 2017] [core:notice] [pid 587] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Jul 19 14:34:27.499636 2017] [core:notice] [pid 587] AH00052: child pid 918 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Jul 19 15:48:42.277788 2017] [core:notice] [pid 587] AH00052: child pid 6725 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Jul 19 16:03:10.435325 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 587] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Jul 19 16:04:44.334204 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 572] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Jul 19 16:04:44.391125 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 572] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 19 16:04:44.392095 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 572] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Jul 19 16:04:44.648082 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 572] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 19 16:04:44.648119 2017] [core:notice] [pid 572] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Jul 20 03:22:02.015317 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 572] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Thu Jul 20 03:22:02.109887 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 572] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Jul 20 03:22:02.114118 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 572] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Jul 20 03:22:02.228318 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 572] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 20 03:22:02.228339 2017] [core:notice] [pid 572] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Jul 20 03:43:47.687144 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 572] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Jul 20 03:45:24.079667 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 532] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Jul 20 03:45:24.116354 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 532] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Jul 20 03:45:24.117538 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 532] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Jul 20 03:45:24.367893 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 532] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 20 03:45:24.367943 2017] [core:notice] [pid 532] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Fri Jul 21 03:34:01.565426 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 532] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Fri Jul 21 03:34:01.597084 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 532] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jul 21 03:34:01.597788 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 532] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jul 21 03:34:01.622501 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 532] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 21 03:34:01.622525 2017] [core:notice] [pid 532] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sat Jul 22 03:27:01.916200 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 532] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sat Jul 22 03:27:01.981867 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 532] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Jul 22 03:27:01.982645 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 532] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sat Jul 22 03:27:02.006622 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 532] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 22 03:27:02.006648 2017] [core:notice] [pid 532] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jul 23 03:11:01.397763 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 532] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sun Jul 23 03:11:01.454335 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 532] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jul 23 03:11:01.455017 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 532] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 23 03:11:01.476079 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 532] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 23 03:11:01.476099 2017] [core:notice] [pid 532] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jul 23 18:23:23.218063 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 532] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun Jul 23 18:24:54.094377 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 570] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Jul 23 18:24:54.127317 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 570] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jul 23 18:24:54.128106 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 570] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 23 18:24:54.394225 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 570] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 23 18:24:54.394263 2017] [core:notice] [pid 570] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Jul 24 00:32:30.456050 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 570] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

Thanks a ton!!

Comment: SIGWINCH means your process is in a window that was resized -- the signal is intended to tell a shell that it should interrogate the terminal to get updated info about window size so it can reformat its output. Why are you running a server from a terminal window anyhow? If you're in a modern CentOS release using systemd, create a systemd service.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a software development question -- it's really more about correctly *deploying* services (that being a system administration function) than writing them.